# Creating Conditional Indices on Transactional Data in R

Tags: r, indexing, conditional-statements

I have a data set with transaction data in order.  I have Field1, Field2, Field3, and Numeric1 already.  How do I create Index1 & Index2 in the table below?  First A/BB/CCC shows up (Index1 = 1) five times (Index2 = 1 through 5).  Next, A/BB/ddd shows up for the first time (Index1 = 1) with three records (Index2 = 1 through 3).  After that, A/BB/CCC comes back again for four more records (Index1 = 2 and Index2 = 1 through 4).  This interchanging occurs until Field1 = A no longer exists.  Now we move on to Field1 = T and the whole process starts over.

For an example, imagine two people are playing mini golf.  Field1 represents the date of each game, Field2 & Field3 represent categorical variables, Numeric1 represents distance.  Index1 would represent which hole they are on.  Index2 would represent the number of strokes they took.

Thanks for your help.

```
Field1  Field2  Field3  Numeric1   Index1  Index2
  A       BB      CCC       4         1       1
  A       BB      CCC       2         1       2
  A       BB      CCC      12         1       3
  A       BB      CCC      25         1       4
  A       BB      CCC      -4         1       5

  A       BB      ddd       30        1       1
  A       BB      ddd       8         1       2  
  A       BB      ddd       1         1       3 

  A       BB      CCC       4         2       1
  A       BB      CCC      21         2       2
  A       BB      CCC      12         2       3
  A       BB      CCC      -4         2       4

  A       BB      ddd      25         2       1
  A       BB      ddd       9         2       2  
  A       BB      ddd      -1         2       3 

  A       BB      CCC       9         3       1
  A       BB      CCC      -3         3       2
  A       BB      CCC       1         3       3

  A       BB      ddd       5         3       1

  A       BB      CCC       3         4       1
  A       BB      CCC       3         4       2
  A       BB      CCC       4         4       3
  A       BB      CCC      20         4       4
  A       BB      CCC      51         4       5

   ...

  T       BB      CCC       6         1       1
  T       BB      CCC       5         1       2
  T       BB      CCC      13         1       3
```

Code to reproduce (from @michaelvine):

```
  Field1<-rep("A", 24)
  Field2<-rep("BB", 24)
  Field3<-c(rep("CCC", 5), rep("ddd",3),rep("CCC", 4), rep("ddd",3),rep("CCC", 3), rep("ddd",1),rep("CCC", 5))
  Numeric1<-c(4,2,12,25,-4,6,2,1,4,21,12,-4,6,2,1,9,-3,1,-4,3,3,4,20,51)
  Test_df<-data.frame(Field1,Field2,Field3,Numeric1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data.table...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Test_df)

# create group ids based on sequences
Test_df[, g0 := rleid(Field1, Field2, Field3)]

# rebase group ids
Test_df[, gid := rleid(g0), by=.(Field1, Field2, Field3)]

# create row-within-group ids
Test_df[, rid := rowid(g0)]
```

which gives

```
    Field1 Field2 Field3 Numeric1 g0 gid rid
 1:      A     BB    CCC        4  1   1   1
 2:      A     BB    CCC        2  1   1   2
 3:      A     BB    CCC       12  1   1   3
 4:      A     BB    CCC       25  1   1   4
 5:      A     BB    CCC       -4  1   1   5
 6:      A     BB    ddd        6  2   1   1
 7:      A     BB    ddd        2  2   1   2
 8:      A     BB    ddd        1  2   1   3
 9:      A     BB    CCC        4  3   2   1
10:      A     BB    CCC       21  3   2   2
11:      A     BB    CCC       12  3   2   3
12:      A     BB    CCC       -4  3   2   4
13:      A     BB    ddd        6  4   2   1
14:      A     BB    ddd        2  4   2   2
15:      A     BB    ddd        1  4   2   3
16:      A     BB    CCC        9  5   3   1
17:      A     BB    CCC       -3  5   3   2
18:      A     BB    CCC        1  5   3   3
19:      A     BB    ddd       -4  6   3   1
20:      A     BB    CCC        3  7   4   1
21:      A     BB    CCC        3  7   4   2
22:      A     BB    CCC        4  7   4   3
23:      A     BB    CCC       20  7   4   4
24:      A     BB    CCC       51  7   4   5
    Field1 Field2 Field3 Numeric1 g0 gid rid
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely understand, however, due to my lack of reputation and my inability to comment, I will provide this as an answer. Index3 is my addition, it is a simple paste0() with the transactions based on my interpretation of the question and example. 
hope this helps,

```
  Field1<-rep("A", 24)
  Field2<-rep("BB", 24)
  Field3<-c(rep("CCC", 5), rep("ddd",3),rep("CCC", 4), rep("ddd",3),rep("CCC", 3), rep("ddd",1),rep("CCC", 5))
  Numeric1<-c(4,2,12,25,-4,6,2,1,4,21,12,-4,6,2,1,9,-3,1,-4,3,3,4,20,51)
  Index1<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4)
  Index2<-c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,1,2,3,5,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,1,2,3,4,5)
  Test_df<-data.frame(Field1,Field2,Field3,Numeric1,Index1,Index2)
  Test_df$Index3<-paste0(Test_df$Field1,"-",Test_df$Field2,"-",Test_df$Field3,"-",Test_df$Index1,"-",Test_df$Index2)
```

Comment: The question assumes that you have the first four columns but not the Index columns.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to capture these.